# Cambiar el value de un input que esta dentro de un while al darle click a un checkbox

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un input con el value llenado con datos de la base de datos recorido por un while entonces cuando cambio el valor solo cambia el primer input y los demas no

```
<?php   $primero = $con->consulta("SELECT cobros.dias_mora, cobros.periodo, cobros.fechaIngreso, cobros.horaIngreso FROM cobros WHERE cobros.id_asignacion = '$_GET[cod]' AND cobros.estado = 'Pendiente' AND cobros.periodo <= '$_GET[periodo]' GROUP BY periodo");
while ($pri = $con->arreglo($primero)) {        ?>

         <div id="bloque" style="display: block">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="border-left-width: 2px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: #192a54; ; border-top: 1px dotted #192A54;"><input type="checkbox" name="periodo[]" id="periodo" onclick="check3()"  checked  value="<?php echo $pri["periodo"]; ?>">
              <?php echo $pri["periodo"]; ?></td>
            <td   align="center" style="border-left-width: 2px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: #192a54; border-top: 1px dotted #192A54;">

                <input id="dm" type="text" style="border: 0;" value="<?php echo $pri["dias_mora"]; ?>">
                <script>
                function check3(){

<?php   $primero2 = $con->consulta("SELECT cobros.dias_mora, cobros.periodo, cobros.fechaIngreso, cobros.horaIngreso FROM cobros WHERE cobros.id_asignacion = '$_GET[cod]' AND cobros.estado = 'Pendiente' AND cobros.periodo <= '$_GET[periodo]' GROUP BY periodo");
        while ( $con->arreglo($primero2)) { ?>
  if(document.getElementById("dm").style.display == "none")
    document.getElementById("dm").style.display = "block";
  else
    document.getElementById("dm").value = "0.0";

<?php } ?>
}    

 </script>
</td>
```

Comment: no entiendo cual es tu duda o problema concretamente?

Comment: tengo un checkbox al darle click cambia el valor del input a 0.0 pero como los input estan creados por un buque whlile solo hace el cambio en el primer input y no en los demas

Comment: entonces lo que quieres es que a todos se coloque el mismo value?

Comment: no, lo que quiero que según el checkbox  que chequee se quite el valor que muerta de la base de datos y coloque el 0.0

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se puede hacer es agregar un contador para que el id vaya cambiando dependiendo del los " n " checkbox que tengas

```
<?php   $primero = $con->consulta("SELECT cobros.dias_mora, cobros.periodo, cobros.fechaIngreso, cobros.horaIngreso FROM cobros WHERE cobros.id_asignacion = '$_GET[cod]' AND cobros.estado = 'Pendiente' AND cobros.periodo <= '$_GET[periodo]' GROUP BY periodo");
$i=0; //se utiliza para cambiar el id de los input's
while ($pri = $con->arreglo($primero)) {        ?>

         <div id="bloque" style="display: block">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="border-left-width: 2px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: #192a54; ; border-top: 1px dotted #192A54;"><input type="checkbox" name="periodo[]" id="periodo" onclick="check3(<?php echo $i?>)"  checked  value="<?php echo $pri["periodo"]; ?>">
              <?php echo $pri["periodo"]; ?></td>
            <td   align="center" style="border-left-width: 2px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: #192a54; border-top: 1px dotted #192A54;">

                <input id="dm<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" style="border: 0;" value="<?php echo $pri["dias_mora"]; ?>">
                <script>
                function check3(valor){

<?php   $primero2 = $con->consulta("SELECT cobros.dias_mora, cobros.periodo, cobros.fechaIngreso, cobros.horaIngreso FROM cobros WHERE cobros.id_asignacion = '$_GET[cod]' AND cobros.estado = 'Pendiente' AND cobros.periodo <= '$_GET[periodo]' GROUP BY periodo");
        while ( $con->arreglo($primero2)) { ?>
  if(document.getElementById("dm"+valor).style.display == "none")
    document.getElementById("dm"+valor).style.display = "block";
  else
    document.getElementById("dm"+valor).value = "0.0";

<?php } 

$i++; // incrementamos i para el cambio del id

?>
}    

 </script>
</td>
```

Comment: exacto. me funciono muchas gracias¡¡¡¡¡

Comment: de nada y mucha suerte en el área :)

Comment: si una consulta mas y para devolverle el valor al input osea al desmarcar el checkbox  volverla a poner el valor de la base de datos

Comment: te recomendaria que volvieras a hacer la consulta donde solo trajeras el valor original

Comment: dentro de la función ?

Comment: si, dentro de la funcion

Comment: ya lo intente y no me resulta tengo esto en la función   if(document.getElementById("dm"+valor).value == "0")
     
      
      document.getElementById("dm"+valor).value= "00";

  else
    document.getElementById("dm"+valor).value = "0"; y en lugar del 00 debajo del if quiero que le asigne el value el valor que tenia en la base de datos

Comment: lo que se puede hacer el ver cuando el checkbox cambio de estado

Answer (score 0):

intentaste con tu IF dentro del primer While??

```
<?php   $primero = $con->consulta("SELECT cobros.dias_mora, cobros.periodo, cobros.fechaIngreso, cobros.horaIngreso FROM cobros WHERE cobros.id_asignacion = '$_GET[cod]' AND cobros.estado = 'Pendiente' AND cobros.periodo <= '$_GET[periodo]' GROUP BY periodo");
while ($pri = $con->arreglo($primero)) {        ?>
<?php
if(document.getElementById("dm").style.display == "none")
document.getElementById("dm").style.display = "block";
else
document.getElementById("dm").value = "0.0"; 
?>
<div id="bloque" style="display: block">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="border-left-width: 2px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: #192a54; ; border-top: 1px dotted #192A54;"><input type="checkbox" name="periodo[]" id="periodo" onclick="check3()"  checked  value="<?php echo $pri["periodo"]; ?>">
          <?php echo $pri["periodo"]; ?></td>
        <td   align="center" style="border-left-width: 2px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: #192a54; border-top: 1px dotted #192A54;">

            <input id="dm" type="text" style="border: 0;" value="<?php echo $pri["dias_mora"]; ?>">
            <script>
            function check3(){
<?php   $primero2 = $con->consulta("SELECT cobros.dias_mora, cobros.periodo, cobros.fechaIngreso, cobros.horaIngreso FROM cobros WHERE cobros.id_asignacion = '$_GET[cod]' AND cobros.estado = 'Pendiente' AND cobros.periodo <= '$_GET[periodo]' GROUP BY periodo");
    while ( $con->arreglo($primero2)) { ?>
<?php } ?>}
</script>
```

Deberias revisar tus llaves de cierre de sentencias. al parecer faltan (y/o sobran) entre otros detalles. Suerte!

Comment: si colocabas el if dentro del primer while obtenías los resultados esperados o te quedaste con tu solucion solamente?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando el checkbox cambio su estado puedes utilizar JQuery

```
$("#dm"+valor).on( 'change', function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        //colocar valor si esta seleccionado
    } else {
        // Hacer algo si el checkbox ha sido deseleccionado
        <?php   $primero2 = $con->consulta("SELECT cobros.dias_mora FROM cobros WHERE cobros.id_asignacion = '$_GET[cod]' AND cobros.estado = 'Pendiente' AND cobros.periodo <= '$_GET[periodo]' GROUP BY periodo");?>
  //colocar el nuevo valor 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check3(valor){

  if(document.getElementById("dm"+valor).value == "0")
        <?php   $primero2 = $con->consulta("SELECT cobros.dias_mora FROM cobros WHERE cobros.id_asignacion = '$_GET[cod]' AND cobros.estado = 'Pendiente' AND cobros.periodo <= '$_GET[periodo]' ");
      $ri=$con->arreglo($primero2);
      ?>
  //colocar el nuevo valor 

     window.parent.document.getElementById("dm"+valor).value = '<?php echo $ri['dias_mora']; ?>';

  else
    document.getElementById("dm"+valor).value = "0";



<?php $i++; // incrementamos i para el cambio del id ?>
}    

 </script>
//meti la consulta como me dijo funciona pero solo manda el primer id cuando lo hago con el siguiente me muestra el primer dato lo intente meter en un while para recorrerlo pero no funciona
```

Comment: Cuál de las dos es la respuesta correcta amigo?

Comment: esta donde pongo la consulta sql dentro de la function

Comment: Convendría aclares cuál de las dos es tu respuesta final, unifiques contenidos y elimines la otra

Comment: ya elimine el otro comentario